# How to create a perspective shadow with CSS only?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I know about the `box-shadow` property in CSS, but this produces a shadow that looks like being projected on a wall right behind the element. I need to create a shadow that looks like the element is standing on the ground like this:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/150);
  margin-left: 20px;
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve this without using the [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) property on the element itself, but on the pseudo element [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before).

- `transform: skewX(60deg);` will make it look like the light source is coming from the side
- `height: 10%;` will make it look like projected on the ground
- `width: 70%` and some positioning will hide the actual element
- And at last `box-shadow: -25px -4px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.75);` will produce the shadow

Of course for older browsers you should use vendor prefixes.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/150);
  margin-left: 30px;
}
div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 15px;
  height: 10%;
  width: 70%;
  box-shadow: -25px -4px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  transform: skewX(60deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Wait, what, did you just answer your own question in a 2nd person context?

Comment: I just wanted to [share knowledge in Q&A-Style](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)... :)

Comment: Ha, nice! well explained!