# Unexpected NaN value when parsing the attribute on after content + z-index

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, z-index

I have a really weird issue, here it is : 
i  wanted to create a perspective shadow like this topic (::after instead in my case) [How to create a perspective shadow with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40357225/how-to-create-a-perspective-shadow-with-css)

```
div {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 background: url(//placehold.it/150x150);
 margin-left: 30px;
}
div::before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 15px;
 height: 10%;
 width: 70%;
 box-shadow: -25px -4px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 transform: skewX(60deg);
}
```

and then when i load my webpage and then i click on "inspect element" from firefox and click on something in the code, i've got this issue "Unexpected NaN value when parsing the attribute", i searched on forum and people said that it may be a Qjery problem but when i delete this ::after everything is good. 
here is my Javascript file:

```
function styleTabHover(tabButton){
    tabButton.style.color= "#ff9900";


}
function styleTabOut(tabButton){
    tabButton.style.color= "white";
    tabButton.style.borderColor= "white"; 
}
function check_email(ev){
    var champ = ev.currentTarget;
    if(!champ.value.includes("@")){
        champ.style.outline = "2px dotted red";
        document.getElementById("champ_requis").style.opacity = "1";
    }else{
        champ.style.outline = "none";
        document.getElementById("champ_requis").style.opacity = "0";
    }
}
function changeTab(idbouton){


    var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("menu_bouton");
    console.log(tabs,"changetab fonction lancé")

    var i;

    for (i=0;i<tabs.length;i++){
        tabs[i].style.backgroundColor = "initial";
        tabs[i].style.zIndex = "0";
        tabs[i].onmouseover = function(){styleTabHover(this)};
        tabs[i].onmouseout = function(){styleTabOut(this)};

    }


    var bouton = document.getElementById(idbouton);

    bouton.style.background = "#ff9900";
    bouton.style.color = "white";
    bouton.onmouseover= function(){this.style.cursor = "default"};
}

var imgPositionMoins = 0;
function style_projet_slide(droite){

    var lst_projetImg = document.getElementsByClassName("projets_img");




    var i;
    if(droite && (imgPositionMoins > (-100*(lst_projetImg.length-1)) ) ){
        imgPositionMoins -= 100;
        for(i=0;i<lst_projetImg.length;i++){

            lst_projetImg[i].style.left = imgPositionMoins+"%";
        }

    }else if ( !droite && imgPositionMoins < 0){

        imgPositionMoins += 100;
        for(i=lst_projetImg.length-1; i>=0; i--){

            lst_projetImg[i].style.left = imgPositionMoins+"%";

        }
    }


}
function projet_desc(indice){
    var lst_desc=document.getElementById("projet_desc").children;
    var i;
    for (i=0;i<lst_desc.length;i++){
        if (i==indice){
            lst_desc[i].style.display = "block";
        } else{
            lst_desc[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    window.scroll({ 
      top: 800,
      left: 0,
      behavior: 'smooth' 
    });

}
```

**another problem** i get, when i use z-index -1 when i load the webpage, i see the ::before content during 1 second which is supposed to be behind the main content. So, i tried to use a positive z-index as people said but it doesnt work when i put a higher z-index on the main content. I saw that i have to put position:relative but on the official doc. it shows that we can do an absolute position.
Can someone help me ? Thanks !

Comment: Can you post some fiddle, or code pen example when we can reproduce the bug? And what version of FF, win , mac v?

Comment: there are several pages and i dont know where the issue come from, i will edit to put my JS file, hopefully it will help you , and im on windows .